# How do you pass and execute a mysql query?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I was wondering how to execute a mysql query so that the client can see like "users registered: *number*"

Server.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var fs = require('fs');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'kitsune',
    connectionLimit: 50,
    port: 3306 });

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});
module.exports = connection;

http.createServer(function(req,res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

  fs.readFile('index.html', 'utf-8', function(err, content) {
    if (err) {
      res.end('error occurred');
      return;
    }
    var countQuery = "SELECT Count(ID) AS NumberOfPenguins FROM Penguins"; console.log(countQuery);
connection.query(countQuery, function(err, rows) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Connected!');
});

    var renderedHtml = ejs.render(content, {countQuery: countQuery});
    res.end(renderedHtml);
  });
}).listen(80);
```

index.html:

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
<body>
Users registered: <%= countQuery %>
</body>
</html>
```

This only shows the query but it does not execute it. Any idea on how to execute it?

Comment: You need to process the results of your query. connection.query(countQuery, ... returns a result that should contain what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You executed the query sure but you never did anything with the results. The result is the `rows` passed in the callback function.

```
connection.query(countQuery, function(err, rows) {
  if (err) throw err;

  var renderedHtml = ejs.render(content, {countQuery: rows});
  res.end(renderedHtml);
});
```

Comment: I will take a look at this tomorrow as I am on my phone right now. Thanks for taking your time to help.

Comment: This did not work as it returned the query in plain or [object Object]

Comment: Try changing the `<%=` in your ejs file to `<%-` @JavaSherwood

Comment: didn't work. Gave back the sql query and still gave [object Object] with the above answer. It's not executing the query for some reason.

Comment: Try stringifying the rows before sending `countQUERY: JSON.stringify(rows)})` @JavaSherwood

Comment: This didn't do anything. And it is:
`JSON.stringify(rows);`

Comment: But, `console.log(JSON.stringify(rows));` did do what I wanted, but just on the console.

Comment: I put the countQuery there and the remaining brackets to provide context on where I meant you should put it.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!
`var renderedHtml = ejs.render(content, {countQuery: JSON.stringify(rows)});`